# Authentication Required Pop Up on RDLC Report Viwer Page

Tags: sql, asp.net, rdlc

I have created RDLC report in my application and display this report using ReportViewer control configured Locally. It is working fine on localhost but could not work on my hosting server. When i open this page, Authentication is required pop up comes up. Rest of the pages (w/o report) are working fine.

Thanks and Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is late but it may help someone I found solution [here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1179668.aspx). It could be port and location issue.